# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table ' ' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay so I googled and found an endless amount of results obviously, but none of them were helpful.

The error seem to be self explanatory... but I don't see what I'm doing wrong in this case:

```
    CREATE TABLE Contrat
(ID_contrat int identity(1,1),
ID_client int,
code_contrat int,
date_début date,
date_fin date,
status_contrat varchar(20),
Totalité int,
montant_mensuel int,
CONSTRAINT PK_composed2 primary key(ID_contrat,ID_client,code_contrat),
CONSTRAINT FK_3 foreign key(code_contrat) references type_contract(code_type_contract) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK_4 foreign key(ID_Client) references Clients(ID_Client) ON DELETE CASCADE
)



CREATE TABLE FonctionContract
(ID_FonctionContract int identity(1,1),
ID_contract int,
ID_fonction int,
nombre int,
prix_unitaire numeric(16,2),
Constraint PK_composed primary key(ID_fonctionContract, ID_Contract, ID_Fonction),
Constraint FK_11 foreign key(ID_contract) references Contrat(ID_contrat) ON DELETE CASCADE,
Constraint FK_2 foreign key(ID_Fonction) references Fonction(ID_fonction) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

The error is occuring in the before last line (FK_11).
Some results says that I should do a composed foreign key too, but I don't see how when I have `ID_FonctionContract` not being linked anywhere.

Comment: YOur primary key is `(ID_contrat,ID_client,code_contrat)` not `ID_contrat`. A `FOREIGN KEY` must reference **all** of those columns. The error is, in fact, telling you the problem.

Comment: So you're saying that the issue is actually coming from the first table and not the second?

Because as weird as it might soud, the first table is working without issues. I'm having an error on the second table only.

Comment: No, I'm saying the `FOREIGN KEY` you are creating is trying to reference a `UNIQUE INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` that consists of **only** the column `ID_contrat` in the table `Contrat`; and that does not exist. The only `UNIQUE INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` the table `Contrat` is on the columns `ID_contrat,ID_client,code_contrat`, so it is not applicable to a key that only references one of those columns.

Comment: ID_fonctionContract Is just the unique identifier for the table, why would I reference it somewhere?

Comment: `ID_fonctionContract` is the primary key in your table `FonctionContract`; it has nothing to do with the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value of a Foreign Key constraint needs to reference exactly one row of the target table, and the DBMS needs to be able to guarantee this based on the table definitions.

Although the ID_contrat column is defined as auto-incremented, it is not constrained to be unique, because you've defined a multi-column Primary Key on the Contrat table. So the DBMS is saying that a single ID_contrat in your proposed Foreign Key could potentially match multiple rows in the Contrat table, which is not allowed. (This seems surprising, because *you* probably know that it will only match one, but the DBMS doesn't!)

You need to do one of two things:

- Define your foreign key across multiple columns, so that it matches the multiple columns guaranteed to be unique on the other table; that will require you to have all three columns in the FonctionContrat table (ID_contrat, ID_client, and code_contrat)
- Adjust the definition of the Contrat table to say that ID_contrat is in fact unique across all rows, either by changing the Primary Key definition, or adding an additional Unique Constraint on the ID_contrat column

I suspect the second option is the appropriate one here: it's rather unusual to use an auto-increment column and then insert duplicates into it.

What you possibly intended was two different unique constraints / indexes: one on ID_contrat and a separate one on combinations of ID_client and code_contrat. Only one of those can be marked as the Primary Key, but the other can be a Unique Index, which has most of the same functionality in practice; either one can be marked "clustered", which tells SQL Server to physically lay out the table based on that column.

Comment: Are you saying a primary key is not the same thing as a unique key?

Comment: There is a 3rd option, create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `Contrat.ID_contrat`

Comment: @P.Salmon Technically, they are not the same - a table always has exactly one Primary Key, but can have any number of other "candidate keys" which can be defined with unique constraints or unique indexes. In practice, I've not come across anything that treats the Primary Key differently from any other unique key.

Comment: @Larnu That's what I meant by "Add or adjust"; I'll edit to make it more explicit.